# Inheriting Python Class args from Super

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to inherit the `collection` arg from the `Base` class.  How?

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, collection=None, classname=None):
        self.__collection__ = collection or self.__class__.__name__

class Thing(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Thing, self).__init__()
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


t = Thing(collection='foobar')
t.__collection__

>>> 'Thing'
```

:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually use `super()`. I instead call the `__init__` function directly. Something like:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, collection=None, classname=None):
        self.__collection__ = collection or self.__class__.__name__

class Thing(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #super(Thing, self).__init__()
        Base.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        #self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


t = Thing(collection='foobar')
print(t.__collection__)
```

Should yield what you want.

Comment: This works, but I need the `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` so I can pass in a `dict` at instantiation.  `t = Thing(collection='foobar', **{'other':'stuff'})

Comment: In that case, you would need the `Base` class to also accept kwargs. Something like `def __init__(self, collection=None, classname=None, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use double underscores at the beginning of an instance variable, and avoid using them at the beginning and at the end, because double underscore has a special meaning in python.

If an instance variable's identifier starts with a double underscore it is "name mangled" to avoid clashes in the namespaces of the subclasses, and thus `self.__collections` actually becomes `self._Base__collections`.
Double underscore at the beginning and end of an instance variable identifier are reserved for special methods and special names(e.g. `__add__` or `__class__`).

Instance variables should either start with a letter(e.g. `collections`) or a single underscore to denote that they are private(e.g. `_collections`)

Anyway, in your example you are setting a `collection` attribute which does not exist. If you named the attribute `self.collection` in the `Base` class it would work correctly.

To make clear:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def __init__(self, collection=None):
...             self.__collection__ = collection or self.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> class Thing(Base):
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...             super(Thing, self).__init__()
...             self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
... 
>>> t = Thing(collection=3)   __dict__.update creates a new instance attribute
>>> t.__collection__
'Thing'
>>> t.collection   # here it is
3
>>> t = Thing(**{'__collection__': 7})   #UGLY! Do not do this!!!
>>> t.__collection__
7
```

Comment: Not to mention 3 less keystrokes!  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to 'forward' the `kwargs` to your base class' `__init__()` method:

```
class Thing(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Thing, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

t = Thing(collection='foobar')
assert t.__collection__ == 'foobar'
assert t.__dict__.get('collection') == 'foobar'
```

You were simply calling `Base.__init__()` with default arguments.

Comment: This works, but I need the `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` so I can pass in a `dict` at instantiation.  `t = Thing(collection='foobar', **{'other':'stuff'})

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `super(Thing, self).__init__(**kwargs)`?  This will pass the keyword arguments along to the superclass `__init__`.